# how to not have a background layer in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am not a graphic artist, I use Photoshop when I need pieces of graphics cut, sliced, composited, etc and while not an artist, I've been using it a few hours a month since Windows 3, so.. for a while.

There is one thing I that always annoyed me and I never found a solution. Every single time I need it, I open the image I need to work on and I convert the background into a layer.

Is there a way to kill the background layer forever? I understand there are use cases where it's useful but there are also scenarios, like mine, where for 30 years it hasn't been useful and only been a source of 'why the hell? ah yes, it's a background layer instead of a normal one'.

Can I set PS in a way that an image gets loaded as a layer, without a background? (which will then default to transparent)

Comment: It might depend on image type. jpgs & tifs seem to do that, pngs don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ''Load Files into Stack'' command.
go to File-scripts-load files into stack-- this is the way when you deal with multiple images.
And you can stack images as 'layer' in layer panel following this.

But '' an image gets loaded as a layer, without a background'' it's not possible inside Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an action that calls the command from `Layer > New > Layer From Background...` Assign it an F-Key shortcut....

- Open an image
- hit your F-Key
- BAM! no background layer.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible in vanilla Photoshop, but if you *really* hate it:

- if you want this only for new files:

  1. create an Action1 that'll remove the background layer (`Layer From Background...` as Scott mentioned)
  2. optionally create an Action2 with a Condition `if layer is background layer`: and place Action1 to `Then` field
  3. use `File > Scripts > Scripts Event Manager` to assign Action1 (or Action2 if made) to `New Document` event: this way the action will run every time you create a new document — BG layer will be automatically obliterated;
- if you want this on new and opened documents:

  1. write a script that'd check if a document has a BG layer (and if it's not in Indexed Mode) and if it has, remove it.
  2. use the same `Scripts Event Manager` to assign this script to `New Document` *and* `Open Document` events: this way this script will run every time you create or open a document — BG layer will be automatically terminated.